# Why are (Pre)sheaves more important than Co(pre)sheaves?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, topos-theory

I'm learning Sheaf Theory,  and this is an issue that's been bothering me.

Fix a small category $\mathcal{C}$.

A $\mathcal{V}$-valued presheaf on the small category $\mathcal{C}$ is a functor $F:\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}\rightarrow \mathcal{V}$. This determines a category $[\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}},\mathcal{V}]$ where objects are $\mathcal{V}$-valued presheaves, and morphisms are natural transformations between them.

If we impose certain gluing conditions (namely a [Grothendieck Topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_topology) $J$), we can form the full subcategory $\text{Sh}_{\mathcal{V}}(\mathcal{C},J)$ of $[\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}},\mathcal{V}]$ called the category of $\mathcal{V}$-**valued sheaves** on the category $\mathcal{C}$.

There is also a dual notion called a **copresheaf**, which is a functor $F:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \mathcal{V}$, determining a category $[\mathcal{C},\mathcal{V}]$ of **copresheaves** similar to earlier. **Cosheaves** form a category (which I'll denote $\textbf{CoSh}_{\mathcal{V}}(\mathcal{C},J)$) by a similar construction. (One can also view co(pre)sheaves $\mathcal{C}$ as (pre)sheaves on $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$)

If $\mathcal{V}$ is an abelian category, then studying $\text{Sh}_{\mathcal{V}}(\mathcal{C},J)$ gives rise to [Sheaf Cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_cohomology). Also, if $\mathcal{V} = \textbf{Set}$, then $\text{Sh}_{\textbf{Set}}(\mathcal{C},J)$ is a very important example of a topos.

My question is why are (pre)sheaves more studied/important than co(pre)sheaves, when 
$\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}$ are both small categories? Do (pre)sheaves give more important information about the category $\mathcal{C}$ (depending on what one is studying)?

Comment: A simple answer is that the Yoneda embedding $C \to [C^{op}, \text{Set}]$ is covariant. There is a sort of dual to the Yoneda embedding $C \to [C, \text{Set}]^{op}$ but $[C, \text{Set}]^{op}$ isn't a very nice category for various reasons, e.g. it's not locally presentable.